# hibernate criteria query in java

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an ADD form which adds name, start date and end date into a database.  What I want is to make a query which satisfies that if another date is entered for the same name, it will return false. Any suggestions please?

This is what I've tried, but it fails:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = createCriteria();
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("start_date", startDate));
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("end_date", endDate));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));
```